# switchMap: Multiple (2) requests getting triggered

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am using Angular 2 RC-4. I am trying to make a network request whenever there is a change in the input box. But the request is getting called twice.

My code looks like:

**component.ts**

```js
this.term = new Control();

this.suggestions = this.term.valueChanges
      // .debounceTime(1000)
      // check if the search term's length is >= 1
      .filter(term => term && term.length)

      // switchMap only subscribes to one observable at a time so if a new key is
      // pressed before the response of previous request has been recieved, it
      // automatically un-subscribes from the previous observable thus cancelling the previous
      // request.
      .switchMap(term => this._suggestionsService.getSuggestions(term, uuid))
```

**component.html**

```xml
<ul [hidden]='!(suggestions | async)?.length'>
<li *ngFor='let suggestion of suggestions | async'>{{suggestion.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

**suggestion.service.ts**

```js
getSuggestions(term){
 return this.http.get('some-url')
      .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

This makes the network request 2 times. But if I change the code in component slightly and manually subscribe instead of using async pipe, the network request is only made once.

**component.ts**

```js
this.term.valueChanges
  .filter(term => term && term.length)
  .switchMap(term => this._suggestionsService.getSuggestions(term, uuid))
  .subscribe(value => this.suggestions = value);
```

**component.html**

```xml
<ul [hidden]='!suggestions.length'>
<li *ngFor='let suggestion of suggestions'>{{suggestion.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Results are fine in both. Only the number of network requests is my concern. I guess there is some concept about observables that I am missing.

Comment: Did you happen to have 2 `| async` in your template?

Comment: @HarryNinh yes, I have updated the template in the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that there are 2 `async` in the template that causes the observable to be subscribed multiple times and hence the request is made 2 times.

Using `share` will do the trick:

```
this.suggestions = this.term.valueChanges
    .filter(term => term && term.length)
    .switchMap(term => this._suggestionsService.getSuggestions(term, uuid))
    .share();
```

Comment: This was the case for me. I happened to have three `async` pipes in my template, and therefore three requests each. Using the `share()` operator from `rxjs` did it. Thanks!